# Getting Likes count of each posts on a fan page in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get the 'like' count of a post on Facebook?

I got a link `graph.facebook.com/userid_postid` that says says I can do this. But How do I find the user or page ID and the ID of the post?

For example, if take any post on the fan page:
http://www.facebook.com/TipsLearnings of site http://adityabajaj.com

If I make a post on the fan page above, and people like the post, how would I get the number of likes of that post? I want to have that number available to show on a separate website.

Answer (score 4):

You can use FQL

```
SELECT like_info.like_count, share_info.share_count, comment_info.comment_count FROM stream WHERE post_id = 'your_post_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of most recent posts a fan page made by using `/<PAGE_ID>/posts` (which you can find for your page by navigating to `http://graph.facebook.com/myown.easytipsandtricks`, or just use the username) with a valid access token. From that, you get an object that looks like this:

```
"data": [
{
    "id": "22092443056_115909438544849",
    "from": {
        "name": "Starbucks",
        "category": "Food/beverages",
        "id": "22092443056"
    },
    // ...
    "shares": {
        "count": 708
    },
    "likes": {
        "data": [
        {
            "name": "Shanna Gonzales",
            "id": "100000244536406"
        }
        ],
        "count": 17129
    },
    "comments": {
        "count": 759
    }
}
// ... and more posts
```

Accessing the `count` subfield of each of those fields should tell you shares, likes and comments, respectively.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy!
Could you tell me how do i get the access_token programmatically?
Can I hard-code the access_token I just used into the code and use the same again and again for fetching the posts?

Comment: [Start here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and ask another question if you're stuck on something specific. If you need one quickly with which to test, you can use [this tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

Comment: How can you do this without Pagination?  if a post has 17129 likes you have to paginate a bunch of times... Edit: there is a subtle difference between /likes and ?fields=likes

Comment: @EpiX you're right, you do have to paginate. You can mitigate it somewhat by appending a `limit` parameter of up to 5000 on your `/likes` request, but it's been glitchy for me in the past. Your best bet is to capture them as they happen (or close to it).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the comments/likes count without having to paginate by using the fields parameter in combination with `likes.limit(1).summary(true)`. For example, a search api query for pizza below will give you all public posts and their likes count summarized:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=pizza&type=post&fields=id,name,likes.limit(1).summary(true)
```

results (truncated):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "47883936273_659693910762305", 
      "name": "Instagram", 
      "created_time": "2014-02-16T01:15:29+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "100002243084532", 
            "name": "Yvette Martin"
          }
        ], 
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "after": "MTAwMDAyMjQzMDg0NTMy", 
            "before": "MTAwMDAyMjQzMDg0NTMy"
          }, 
          "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/47883936273_659693910762305/likes?limit=1&summary=1&after=MTAwMDAyMjQzMDg0NTMy"
        }, 
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 13682
        }
      }
    }, 
    {
      "id": "136336876521150_314001148754721", 
      "name": "Pizza Box Turns into Plates & Storage Unit!", 
      "created_time": "2014-02-15T21:20:00+0000", 
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "100005373008864", 
            "name": "Liliana Campoli"
          }
        ], 
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "after": "MTAwMDA1MzczMDA4ODY0", 
            "before": "MTAwMDA1MzczMDA4ODY0"
          }, 
          "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/136336876521150_314001148754721/likes?limit=1&summary=1&after=MTAwMDA1MzczMDA4ODY0"
        }, 
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 2792
        }
      }
    }
```